# Applying form attributes via php

Tags: php, html

So I want to apply a `selected="selected"` attribute to one option on a `<select>` aspect of a form. I have an assortment of buttons that `onclick` send a variable to php within the new form

```
<?php  
$day = $_GET['day'];
?>

<option selected='<?php echo "$sunSelect";?>' value="Sunday">Sunday</option> 

<option selected='<?php echo "$monSelect";?>' value="Monday">Monday</option>
```

if I have the buttons send the name of the day, how can i transfer that to
`$sunSelect = "selected";` without making 7 `if` statements in the php section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a loop instead and then you only need one `if()`

```
$days = ['Sunday','Monday'......'Saturday'];

<?php foreach($days as $d):?>    
  <option <?= ($day===$d ?'selected':'')?> value="<?= $d?>"><?= $d?></option> 
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Note that you don't need a value for `selected` attribute.

`<option selected>` works the same in browser as `<option selected="selected">`